# IF ELSE STATEMENT for the Differnce of two columns in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables : badge_master, match_result_updation and team_badges.

The badge_master is the master table where I manually insert the data acc to the excel. On `match_result_updation` I have some columns, `if sum(goal_column1) - sum(goal_column2) = 10`, then the value column1 will get the badge and it will be inserted in team_badges table. I am handling it through trigger but unable to proceed after certain time.

[image: match_result_updation]

The trigger which I tried :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `afterinsert_teamgoals` AFTER INSERT ON `match_result_updation` FOR EACH ROW   

BEGIN  


DECLARE goalCount1 INT(10);  
DECLARE goalCount2 INT(10);  
DECLARE badgeId BIGINT(20);  
DECLARE teamId bigint(20) default 0 ;  


SELECT team1_goal INTO goalCount1 FROM match_result_updation WHERE team1_id = NEW.team1_id  ;  

SELECT team2_goal INTO goalCount2 FROM match_result_updation WHERE team2_id = NEW.team2_id ;  

IF (goalCount1 - goalCount2 >= 10)  

Then  
Insert into team_badges(team_id,badge_id,match_id,timestamp) 
    SELECT  teamId , badgeId , match_id FROM match_result_updation limit 1;   


END IF;
```

Please Assist.

Comment: Your insert is selecting details from a row on _match_result_updation_ , but not any particular row or one related to the selects above it. Is that correct?

Comment: @@ KickStart : Yes..but it will search the condition if the difference is 10 or above it will insert the value for team1_goal  row in team_badges table else it will insert the value for team2_goal  from the  match_result_updation in team_badges table. And in badge_master table the data will be inserted by the front end.. so accordingly badges Id will get assinged in team_badges table.

Comment: It is checking that goalCount1 is 10 or more higher than goalCount2, but not if goalCount2 is 10 or more higher than goalCount1, so not strictly the difference. The INSERT into team badges selects from match_result_updation but doesn't check team1_id or team2_id, so unless there is only a single row on match_result_updation then it is highly unlikely to be inserting a meaningful value.